# how to put the results of this script in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got the following script

```
#!/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/python

import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging
import csv
import time
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

pcode=[]

with open('locs2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:            
        lat = float(line['lat'])
        lon = float(line['lon'])
        g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
        attempts = 1  # number of lookups
        while not(g.ok) and attempts < 4:
            logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: {}'.format(g.debug()))
            time.sleep(2)  # 2 seconds are specified in the API. If you stillget errors, it's because you've reached the daily quota.
            g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
            attempts += 1
        if attempts > 3:
            logging.warning('Daily quota of google lookups exceeded.')
            break
        pcode.append((lat, lon, g.postal))
        logging.info('Geocoding SUCCESS: ({},{},{})'.format(lat,lon,pcode))
```

I'm trying to put all the results of the scripts in a text file with the command line below but it does not work. Why?

```
sys.stdout = open ("Output.txt", "w")
```

Comment: What if you redirect it with ./script.py > Output.txt ?

Comment: Hi Rafael, it does not work alas. That is the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the logging config to send logs to file:

```
 LOG_FILENAME = 'Output.txt'
 logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: I had deleted my previous comment because the OP program uses the `logging` module for its output, it seems to me that things are a bit more complicated than we both expected... here it is a [simple introduction to the `logging` module](http://pymotw.com/2/logging/).

Comment: @gboffi t´s ok, I changed the post.

Comment: Rafael, one more question not entirely related to my original post but not entirely unrelated as well. How do I log the errors that I have? For example, I have these kind of errors (see next comment)

Comment: `## Provider's Attributes
* traceId: f09ac9fad59144aebca6031bc12b4bc7|DB40231539|02.00.106.3100|DB4SCH010061321
* copyright: Copyright © 2014 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation. [...]` How do I log them? Many thanks.

Comment: I managed to know how to do that: put the script in a file , `chmod` it and then run it like that `./name_script.py > results.log`